# Why can't Simple Products with options be grouped?

Tags: product, magento-1.8, custom-options, overrides

## Synopsis

I have a store where-by I create a Grouped Product and associate a number of Simple Products.  When I add custom options to the simple products it is not visible in the Grouped Products' Associated Products Grid neither the Front-End.

However I have implemented a local, custom module to amend this behaviour, but what I would like to know is:

- What are the reasons for this behaviour in Magento?
- Is my module a good/bad idea?

## Sources

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_grouped>Vendor_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped</product_type_grouped>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Group.php**

```
<?php

class Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $allowProductTypes = array();
        $allowProductTypeNodes = Mage::getConfig()
            ->getNode('global/catalog/product/type/grouped/allow_product_types')->children();
        foreach ($allowProductTypeNodes as $type) {
            $allowProductTypes[] = $type->getName();
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->useGroupedLinks()
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->setProduct($this->_getProduct())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            #->addFilterByRequiredOptions() # removed this
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', $allowProductTypes);

        if ($this->getIsReadonly() === true) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $this->_getSelectedProducts()));
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        $parent = get_parent_class(get_parent_class($this));
        return $parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php**

```
<?php

class Vendor_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped
{
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product = null)
    {
        if (! $this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
            $associatedProducts = array();

            if (! Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
                $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
            }

            $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                #->addFilterByRequiredOptions() # removed this
                ->setPositionOrder()
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)));

            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $associatedProducts[] = $item;
            }

            $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
        }
        return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/simple-product-custom-options-in-grouped-product/) is described how to associate simple products(containing custom options) with group product.

So if you wish to have simple products with custom options listed, be sure you don’t set any of the custom options to be required.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Then i'm confused because `addFilterByRequiredOptions()` adds the following query into the collection for associated products `((e.required != '1') OR (e.required IS NULL))` which compensates for both required and not required, thus the article above is not accurate?  Also if you look at the last comments in that article (from 2014) this suggest it's a solution to a version prior to 1.8.

Comment: Did you try? I just tried it on magento version 1.8.0.0 and it works.

Comment: Then it must have been a recent change in 1.8.1.0, and yes when I set custom options on a simple product and they were not required they were omitted from the grouped products associated products (as I have stated above).  In my question you can see the example code is a direct copy of the core code with one line commented out.

Comment: If you have developer mode turned on you will run into warnings when doing this. Bug? Feature? I'm not sure anyone knows. Either way, it's asking for trouble.